# How do I list existing issue labels in Jira?

Tags: jira

I found how to create new labels (by just entering its name in the corresponding issue field) and how to search issues with a specific label (with a JQL query like `labels IN ('mylabel')`, but I can't find a place to view all the existing labels, nor a JQL operator or function to list them.

How do I see which labels already exist? Can I manage (i.e. rename) them too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see all the labels that are existent in a Jira Project do the following:

- Create a new Dashboard (for the desired project)
- Add a label gadget to it
- Again, select the project you want to see the labels from.
- Enter search interval if necessary -> Save it
  -> You will see all the labels.

Comment: Can we list all the stories, but grouped by labels?

Answer (score 0):

we can add...

JQL: label is not EMPTY -> export to CSV > import in excel.

Ask your DBA to list that for you. Simplest way.

No way to manage them. All edit actions will trigger notification to all defined in notification scheme users.